# How can I replace element of array with X

Tags: jquery

Please I’m trying to find minimum value inside my array and replace the minimum value with X for the same element not to be picked as minimum over again

Here is what I did
`Var arr = [3,8,2,5,1]; Var minIndex;`

```
While(arr.indexOf(‘X’) === -1){
minIndex = 0;
$.each(arr,function(index,value){
if (value < arr.[minIndex]){
minIndex = index;
}
});
arr[minIndex] = ‘X’;

}
Console.log(arr);
```

But only the first minimum which is 1 and is replaced with X

I don’t know what I’m doing wrong
Any help please

Replacing element of array with X

Comment: What is this code not doing that you are expecting it to do?

Comment: Yes, only replacing one element

Comment: How many should it replace?

Comment: All the elements

Comment: I’m finding the minimum from the elements and replacing with x so the same element will not be taken as minimum

Comment: All the elements? As in `arr.map(_ => 'X')`?

Comment: Yes… arr is declared and initialized

Comment: I am sorry. I am unable to understand what you are trying to do. Good luck!

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and time to ditch `var` in favor of `let` and `const`.

Comment: Sorry, it's not entirely clear as to what your objective is.  Please post your code as a [mcve], and include an example of a result that you expect.

Comment: *"But only the first minimum which is 1 and is replaced with X"* What does that mean??? The input is `[3,8,2,5,1]` and the output is `[3,8,2,5,'X']` so what is the issue?

Comment: Avoid using curly quotes

Comment: @epascarello… after the first minimum is changed to ‘X’ I want to find the next minimum which should be 2 then change it to ‘X’ as well… in essence I want to pick minimum of the array at each iteration then change to X until all the element is X

Comment: So sort and pop... why bother replacing, just remove them

Comment: I’m trying to solve a static problem… least cost rule… I’m not sure if everyone will understand that

Comment: Yeah I thought of removing but that will affect the index of the other elements which in turn affect the whole program

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not care about the array. Sort the array and remove them as you use them. There is no need to keep looking up the min.

```js
function getLeast(arr) {
  const remaining = [...arr].sort()
  return () => {
    if (!remaining.length) return undefined;
    return remaining.shift();
  }
}

const nums = [3, 8, 2, 5, 1];

const genNums = getLeast(nums);
console.log(genNums()); // 1
console.log(genNums()); // 2
console.log(genNums()); // 3
console.log(genNums()); // 5
console.log(genNums()); // 8
console.log(genNums()); // undefined
```

using a generator

```js
function* getLeast(arr) {
  const remaining = [...arr].sort()
  while (remaining.length) {
    yield remaining.shift();
  }
}

const nums = [3, 8, 2, 5, 1];

const genNums = getLeast(nums);
console.log(genNums.next().value); // 1
console.log(genNums.next().value); // 2
console.log(genNums.next().value); // 3
console.log(genNums.next().value); // 5
console.log(genNums.next().value); // 8
console.log(genNums.next().value); // undefined
```

replacing with `x` which is not the greatest solution

```js
const nums = [3, 8, 2, 5, 1];

function getLeast(array) {
  const result = array.reduce((obj, value, index) => {
    if (value === 'X') return obj;
    return (!obj || obj.value > value) ? {
      value,
      index
    } : obj;
  }, null)

  if (!result) return;
  array.splice(result.index, 1, 'X');
  return result.value;
}


console.log(getLeast(nums));
console.log(getLeast(nums));
console.log(getLeast(nums));
console.log(getLeast(nums));
console.log(getLeast(nums));
console.log(getLeast(nums));
```